# Accessing optional values of a Swift dictionary

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, dictionary, swift

I defined my dictionary parsed from JSON as [String: AnyObject]

Then I try to access its values;

```
var vote: Int?

if let voteValue: AnyObject = dictionary["vote"] {
    self.vote = voteValue as? Int
}
```

Is there an easier/cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can only think of:

```
var vote: Int?
vote = dictionary["vote"] as AnyObject? as? Int
```

Comment: looks good, any ideas on how to write a generic function for this so that I don't have to use AnyObject casting for every value of the dictionary? We know the type of the dictionary, so the function should receive a string key, cast it to AnyObject? and then cast to specified type in the parameter

Comment: You can check out this library: https://github.com/lingoer/SwiftyJSON. Seems pretty useful.